# Three.js dentmodifier

Tags: three.js

I have been trying to use dent modifier for 3D vehicle loaded using objmtl loader. The model is loaded using multiple obj and mtl files. While I am trying to create dent it is not crating the dent on selected portion. Also when I call computeFaceNormals the model itself is getting distorted. I am not sure if the issue is in my obj files itself. I have attached all obj files as well as the html that I am trying. Can someone please guide me where I am going wrong @mrdoob
issue can be found at http://tinyurl.com/oc4j76a

Comment: `DentModifier` is not currently part of the three.js r.67 library or the three.js examples. It is also very limited in its capability. I think you are going to have to debug your code yourself.

Comment: thank you for looking into this. Dent modifier works perfectly for sphere and box geometry, but not in model I am using. Can you guide me on which direction I can debug in this case?

Comment: Sorry, I can answer questions about three.js, but I cannot help you debug your code. `DentModifier` does require a highly-tessellated geometry to work.